# How to fix “Bad minute” error while installing a new crontab

Tags: 16.04, cron

I've installed a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 to replace my Windows OS.

I'm trying to setup cronjobs to run mangento 2.1 via Ampps softaculous. The software has been successfully installed (both ampps and magento) and it's running well. 
I'm trying to setup a crontab but it seems there is an error on the first line second 25.

This is what I'm trying to add in to the crontab for the Ampps user, using the command `sudo crontab -e -u ampps`

```
* * * * * /usr/local/ampps/php-5.6/etc
/usr/local/ampps/www/localshop.dev/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /usr/local/ampps/www/localshop.dev/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/local/ampps/php-5.6/etc
/usr/local/ampps/www/localshop.dev/update/cron.php >> /usr/local/ampps/www/localshop.dev.dev/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/local/ampps/php-5.6/etc
/usr/local/ampps/www/localshop.dev.dev/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /usr/local/ampps/www/localshop.dev.dev/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

What am I doing wrong?

I followed an error message in magento 2.1 admin that referred to [this troubleshoot link for the version 2.0](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/cron.html)
and to [this configuration guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/post-install-config.html#post-install-cron)

Comment: First glance: you may have lines which have no `* * * * *` so `cron` can't interpret the items.  Crontabs are ***line-break delimited*** to state "This task runs with the given configuration, and that task runs with a different one, etc.".  Is this just a formatting screwup with your copy/paste or do the linebreaks actually exist between `/usr/local/ampps/php-5.6/etc` and the rest of the lines as the code-formatting shows?

Comment: Hey Thomas thanks about that, when you mentioned line break i did check the formating and it helped fix the crontab that has been now installed.  I did also changed the format in 30 20 * * * and seems working now.

Comment: Hi, I understand the problem neither from yr post not from the given comments and answer. Have you modified yr post after receiving comments and perhaps after accepting the answer ? Comments and accepted answer both refer to errors in yr proposed `crontab` entries, that are either not there or not recognizable anymore. It's ok to correct a typo or a bad phrasing, but not an error if, in doing so, you take away the meaning of yr post. In that case yr readers cannot understand anymore what the prbm was. Am I wrong here ?

Comment: @Cbhihe thanks for your comment. Your are absolutely right, I did edit the post once received Thomas W.  comment and terdon answer and the question doesn't make sense anymore now. Sorry about that.  I'm going to copy back linebreakes into the question so it will make sense.

Comment: This error happends when the volume of crontab file is full.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Each crontab line must start with a time at which the command should be run and then the command. The general format is:

```
Min Hour Day Month DayOfWeek Command
```

So, to run `command` at 10:15 every Sunday, you'd do:

```
15 10 * * 0 command
```

I'm not sure what your commands are, but you have lines that don't start with a time definition. I don't understand what lines like this are:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/ampps/php-5.6/etc
```

That's a time but no command. You're giving it a directory. And lines like this have commands but no time:

```
/usr/local/ampps/www/localshop.dev/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /usr/local/ampps/www/localshop.dev/var/log/magento.cron.log
```

So, make sure you follow the format and you should be fine. If this is not clear, edit your question and explain what commands you are trying to run.

Answer (score 6):

From my previous experience, it was due to a CR/LF character before the first cron line (since it was edited from Windows not Linux directly).
I noticed and removed that char from a HEX editor.

Comment: You should expand on your answer with more details.

Comment: If you see '-':1: bad minute, the - is /l. Linux uses LF while windows uses CR/LF. In other words, it would be trying to read the /l character as the first character of the command instead of being part of the new line character.

Comment: How to fix: https://superuser.com/a/52140/390269

Answer (score 5):

This kind of error may also occur if you are trying to reset cron variables to empty values like this:

```
MAILTO=me@example.com
* * * * * do some stuff with error reporting
MAILTO=
* * * * * do another stuff too verbose to receive emails
```

Note the empty line after `MAILTO=` at line 3. This will result in the message:

```
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.AvDwzo":3: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit?
```

The correct way to reset `MAILTO` variable is to use empty quotes, like this:

```
MAILTO=''
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

This error also happens if your /var/spool/cron partition is 100% full. Check your free disk space and make sure you have a few bytes free there.

Answer (score 2):

In my case (and it seems to be OP's case as well), the issue was that I had a new line in the command to be executed, something like this

```
5 0 * * * some_command -some_param
-another_param
```

The overflowing line was of course interpreted as a new cron entry, and cron rightfully complained that the start of **that** line was not a valid minute identifier.

Answer (score 0):

The following command fixed my problem with this issue

```
perl -pi -e 's|\r\n|\n|' /var/spool/cron/root
```

The problem was that Windows line separators (CRLF) were upsetting the Linux based cron. Changing the separators to be Linux line separators (LF) fixed the problem.

Comment: I tried this, it deleted the content of my crontab

Comment: It happend because the drive was full

Answer (score 0):

It can be an error while copy pasting from text editor. Everything should be in one line, e.g.:

Wrong:

```
source your-venv/basch/etc
python3 /yourhome/directory/manage.py
```

Correct:

```
source your-venv/basch/etc python3 /yourhome/directory/manage.py
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if the cron's value for the **minute's place** is actually incorrect.

For example, here's a cron to run every 2 minutes:

- Incorrect Cron: `/2 * * * *`
- Correct Cron: `*/2 * * * *`

Further reading: [Help Ubuntu article on Cron and Crontab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto).